# Ruby - Cannot sum up hash values

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby (and programming in general). I have a hash that is using data from an external file, and I'm trying to get the total number of values that are greater than 1500.

[Here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y7Ew.png) Actually, I need both the number of entries and the total value of purchase orders over 1500. The external file is just a column of order numbers and a column of prices. I'm sure there is a very simple solution, but like I said I'm a beginner and can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Here is my code. It's just that last while loop that's causing all the problems. I know that's not the right way to go about it, but I just can't figure out what to do.

```
myhash={}

file=File.open("Purchase Orders.csv", "r")
while !file.eof
  line=file.readline

  key,value=line.chomp.split(",")
  myhash[key]=value
end

total=0
entries=myhash.length
newtotal=0

myhash.each { |key,value|
  total+=value.to_f
}
puts total
puts entries

while value.to_f>1500
  myhash.each {|key,value| newtotal+=value.to_f}
end

puts newtotal
```

Comment: Hi, it is better that you copy and paste your code directly into your post here. We can't really use it otherwise!

Comment: Okay, fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any sorting here.

Comment: Sorry, "sorting" was the wrong word. And thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will rewrite the code in ruby idiomatic way in hope you’ll examine it and find out some hints.

```
prices = File.readlines("Purchase Orders.csv").map do |line|
  line.chomp.split(",").last.to_f
end # array of prices

total = prices.inject(:+) # sum values
pricy = prices.select { |v| v > 1500 }

pricy_sum = pricy.inject(:+) # sum expensives
pricy_count = pricy.length   # expensives’ size

puts "Total sum is: #{total}"
puts "Total expensives is: #{pricy}"
```

Comment: Sam also wants the number of pricy elements. I suggest removing `inject` from `pricy` and then having `pricy_sum = pricy.inject(&:+)` and `privy_count = pricy.length`

Comment: @ReggieB indeed, thanks, updated. Also, please note, you don’t need to `&` symbols in calls to `inject`, the latter accepts `Symbol` instances.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have your loops reversed. Also, using do and end is usually preferred over curly braces for multiline code blocks, while curly braces are generally used for single line blocks (as noted by @mudasobwa). Check out the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) for some more style pointers.

```
myhash.each do |key,value| 
    newtotal+=value.to_f if value.to_f > 1500
end
puts newtotal
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def nbr_and_tot(fname)
  File.foreach(fname).with_object({ nbr_over: 0, tot_over: 0 }) do |line, h|
    n = line[/\d+/].to_i     
    if n > 1500
      h[:nbr_over] += 1
      h[:tot_over] += n
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

First let's create a file "temp":

```
str =<<-END
:cat, 1501
:dog, 1500
:pig, 2000
END

File.write("temp", str)
  #=> 33
```

Confirm the file is correct:

```
puts File.read("temp")
```

prints

```
:cat, 1501
:dog, 1500
:pig, 2000
```

Now execute the method.

```
nbr_and_tot "temp"
  #=> {:nbr_over=>2, :tot_over=>3501}
```

**Explanation**

First review, as necessary, [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach), which reads the file line-by-line<sup>1</sup> and returns an enumerator that is chained to `with_object`,  [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) and [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

For the example,

```
fname = "temp"
e0 = File.foreach(fname)
  #=> #<Enumerator: File:foreach("temp")>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator (and passed to `each_object`) by converting it to an array:

```
e0.to_a
  #=> [":cat, 1501\n", ":dog, 1500\n", ":pig, 2000\n"]
```

Continuing,

```
e1 = e0.with_object({ nbr_over: 0, tot_over: 0 })
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 2.3.0 :171 >
e1.to_a
  #=> [[":cat, 1501\n", {:nbr_over=>0, :tot_over=>0}],
  #    [":dog, 1500\n", {:nbr_over=>0, :tot_over=>0}],
  #    [":pig, 2000\n", {:nbr_over=>0, :tot_over=>0}]]
```

The first element generated by `e1` is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values, using *parallel assignment*:

```
line, h = e1.next
  #=> [":cat, 1501\n", {:nbr_over=>0, :tot_over=>0}] 
line
  #=> ":cat, 1501\n" 
h #=> {:nbr_over=>0, :tot_over=>0}
```

and `n` is computed:

```
s = line[/\d+/]
  #=> "1501"
n = s.to_i
  #=> 1501
```

As `n > 1500 #=> true`, we perform the following operations:

```
h[:nbr_over] += 1
  #=> 1 
h[:tot_over] += n
  #=> 1501
```

so now

```
h #=> {:nbr_over=>1, :tot_over=>1501}
```

Now the second element of `e1` is passed to the block and the following steps are performed:

```
line, h = e1.next
  #=> [":dog, 1500\n", {:nbr_over=>1, :tot_over=>1501}] 
line
  #=> ":dog, 1500\n" 
h #=> {:nbr_over=>1, :tot_over=>1501} 
n = line[/\d+/].to_i
  #=> 1500
```

As `n > 1500 #=> fasle`, this line is skipped. The processing of the last element generated by `e1` is similar to that for the first element.

<sup>1 `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File < IO #=> true`), so `IO` class methods such as `foreach` are often invoked on the File class (`File.foreach...`)</sup>.